# How to check a type of a network interface in Qt?

Tags: qt, network-programming, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

My code:

**CheckNetwork.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkInterface>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkConfiguration>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkSession>

namespace Ui {
class CheckNetwork;
}

class CheckNetwork : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CheckNetwork(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CheckNetwork();

protected:
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event);
private slots:
    void reply_finished();
    void network_configuration_manager_updateCompleted();
private:
    Ui::CheckNetwork *ui;
    QNetworkInterface *network_interface;
    QNetworkConfigurationManager *network_configuration_manager;
    QNetworkSession *network_session;
    QNetworkReply *reply;

};
```

**CheckNetwork.cpp**

```
#include "checknetwork.h"
#include "ui_checknetwork.h"


/*

Qt Creator 3.3.1 (opensource)
Qt 5.4.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

*/

CheckNetwork::CheckNetwork(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CheckNetwork)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

CheckNetwork::~CheckNetwork()
{
    delete ui;
}

void CheckNetwork::showEvent(QShowEvent *event){

    ui->textEdit->append("-----------------");
    ui->textEdit->append("NetworkInterfaces");
    ui->textEdit->append("-----------------");
    ui->textEdit->append("UP AND RUNNING:");
    network_interface = new QNetworkInterface();
    foreach (QNetworkInterface interface, network_interface->allInterfaces()) {
        if((interface.flags() & QNetworkInterface::IsUp) && (interface.flags() & QNetworkInterface::IsRunning))
            ui->textEdit->append("\t" + interface.name() + " " + interface.humanReadableName() + " " + interface.hardwareAddress());
    }


    ui->textEdit->append("-----------------------------");
    ui->textEdit->append("Network Configuration Manager");
    ui->textEdit->append("-----------------------------");
    ui->textEdit->append("ACTIVE:");
    network_configuration_manager = new QNetworkConfigurationManager(this);
    QObject::connect(network_configuration_manager, SIGNAL(updateCompleted()), this, SLOT(network_configuration_manager_updateCompleted()));
    network_configuration_manager->updateConfigurations();
}


void CheckNetwork::network_configuration_manager_updateCompleted(){
    foreach (QNetworkConfiguration configuration, network_configuration_manager->allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Active)) {
        ui->textEdit->append("\t" + configuration.name() + " " + configuration.bearerTypeName() + " " + configuration.identifier());
    }
    ui->textEdit->append("DEFAULT:");
    ui->textEdit->append("\t" + network_configuration_manager->defaultConfiguration().name() + " " + network_configuration_manager->defaultConfiguration().bearerTypeName());

    ui->textEdit->append("---------------");
    ui->textEdit->append("Network Session");
    ui->textEdit->append("---------------");
    network_session = new QNetworkSession(network_configuration_manager->defaultConfiguration(), this);
    network_session->open();
    if(network_session->isOpen()){
        ui->textEdit->append("\tisOpen");
    }else{
        ui->textEdit->append("\tnoOpen");
    }


    ui->textEdit->append("---------------");
    ui->textEdit->append("Network Manager");
    ui->textEdit->append("---------------");
    QNetworkAccessManager *network_access_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    reply = network_access_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com")));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(reply_finished()));
}



void CheckNetwork::reply_finished(){
    ui->textEdit->append("REPLY: " + QString::number(reply->bytesAvailable()) + " byte(s)");
    ui->textEdit->append("REPLY DATAS: \n\n" + reply->readAll());
}
```

The QTextEdit content with a Wireless (WLAN) network card(win 8.1 64bit):

```
-----------------
NetworkInterfaces
-----------------
UP AND RUNNING:
    {UUID} Wi-Fi XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    {UUID} VirtualBox Host-Only Network XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    {UUID} Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 
    {UUID} Local Network Connexion* 2 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
-----------------------------
Network Configuration Manager
-----------------------------
ACTIVE:
    NetworkWireslessName WLAN XXXXXXXXX
    Local Network Connexion* 2 Unknown XXXXXXXXX
    VirtualBox Host-Only Network Ethernet XXXXXXXXX
    Wi-Fi Ethernet XXXXXXXXX
DEFAULT:
    VirtualBox Host-Only Network Ethernet
---------------
Network Session
---------------
    isOpen
---------------
Network Manager
---------------
REPLY: 256 byte(s)
REPLY DATAS: 

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=66-JVb_aJc7AULSAgcgE">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

The QTextEdit content with a Wired (LAN) network card (Win7 64bit / Win10 32bit):

```
-----------------
NetworkInterfaces
-----------------
UP AND RUNNING:
    {UUID} Local Network Connexion XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    {UUID} Loopback 
-----------------------------
Network Configuration Manager
-----------------------------
ACTIVE:
DEFAULT:

---------------
Network Session
---------------
    noOpen
---------------
Network Manager
---------------
REPLY: 258 byte(s)
REPLY DATAS: 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=ghGJVYecFcq50wX_u4CICg">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

My problem is that I have no way to check the type of the network interface, if it is a " wired or wireless " is in " is online" to prevent networkmanager automatically start the connection network (QNetworkConfigurationManager::CanStartAndStopInterfaces) if the user is not connected because with this verification:

```
network_configuration_manager->defaultConfiguration();
if(!network_configuration_manager->isOnline()){        
        network_configuration_manager->deleteLater();
        return;
}
```

this works perfectly for wireless connections , but as no default configuration is found for a connection cable with this check, the networkmanager can not continue ...in other words , how to check for a connection cable, if a network connection is active (not ping or query a server such as Google ). I read too that for some previous version similar bugs exist. In this version of Qt I have bugs in his box of messages , for example , so would it be a bug? Would anyone information ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to check the bearer type to see if it is a wifi connection ie.:

```
configuration.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN
```

Answer (score 1):

The process should be, I think:

1. Get all network configurations from the manager.
2. For each Active configuration, create the session.
3. Look at the session's interface. Check `QNetworkInterface::flags()` for `QNetworkInterface::IsUp`.

This way you might be able to check for interfaces from non-default sessions as well.

Comment: thank you for your response and your time, but for step 1 you recommend me qt finds no configuration for type interfaces " wired " . Use defautlconfiguration () or allconfiguration () returns me anything like the content of my textEdit above ( I specify that I have no desire to query or anything at all ) just no configuration found for all my network cards type " wired " . I finally decided to handle errors using reply ( QNetworkReply , using his error signal , it seems that my wireless type interface is no longer automatically connect when the execution of the instance of my QNetworkManager )

Comment: for this I want to do this is enough but I 'd like to know where does this problem and I think ultimately has an internal problem QT . Correct me or give me a place to look if I'm wrong I takes me maybe not as it should. thank you again

Comment: This is what I did to begin with, and it worked for me in Linux, but when I tested it in Windows, it failed!  QNetworkSession.interface().isValid() is False in Windows like this!

Comment: It's probably a bug or a not-implemented-yet feature.